# XML Sources Randomly Fail on Execution in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

In SSIS, I have a script task that pulls data and creates and bunch of xml documents. I have those documents read in as xml source tasks, and they all go to an OLE DB. Each time I run the entire package, one or two of the xml source tasks will fail. The failing xml source task appears to be random at first glance. Without changing anything at all, if I run the package again, some different xml source task will fail, or it may run all of them successfully. Running it a third time produces new failures or sometimes success, and so on. It seems like regenerating the XSDs for the xml source that fails temporarily fixes that task, but it always fails again after a number of runs. I usually get the same error on a given xml source task, which looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPvFo.png

I have no idea what is causing this as I am new to SSIS, so any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it be possible in task script to output xml document as of data type dt_iu4 or DT_STR( rather than xml type). Also check what's the data type of the WSOperationMetrics in the XSD, try to map it's output data type accordingly.

Have look of this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb5abc1a-3dbc-4f67-af98-eec359b76ee7/value-was-too-large-to-fit-in-the-output-column?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

Comment: yea changing the data type in the XSD worked. Since different values were comming in, it was guessing incorrectly each time about the data type, which explains the "randomness." Thank you.